# How to schedule the class of java project every 5 mins with crontab on ubuntu?

Tags: cron

I run crontab -e and use this command:
*/5 * * * * /home/Test.war.It does not work.
I wanna execute getDateTime() of Test Class at every 5 mins.

```
    public long getDateTime() throws ParseException{
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

        formatter.setCalendar(calendar);
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Hong_Kong"));

        String newZealandTime = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
        Date d = formatter.parse(newZealandTime);
        long time = (d.getTime()/1000) - 240;
        return time;
    }
```

How can I integrate the java path?

Answer (score 0):

`/home/Test.war` is not an executable file, it is meant to be deployed in a servlet container or in an application server.

A stand alone java application can be compiled to a folder, or put in a jar file, or in an executable jar file. Each of these alternatives will have a different command line to start it involving the `java` command.

For example an executable jar would be invoked as `java -jar <executable jar file>`.

To run it with cron, what I do is write a `shell script` (i.e. my_program.sh), and write the command line to start the java program inside the file (including class path arguments, etc.).
Then give the `shell script` execution permissions.
And finally have `cron` call the shell script.

The crontab expression for every 5 minutes is: `* 0/5 * ? * * *`
[Cron Expression Generator & Explainer - Quartz](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html)